# Replace continuous occurrence of strings with single

Tags: php

**In short**
change contineous occurance of the string value that we specify, with a single string value.
ie

`hello \t\t\t\t\t world \n\n\n\n\t\t\t`

to

`hello \t world \n\t`

**In detail**

```
\n\tExample\n\r\nto \nunderstand\n\r\n the current\n situatuion\t\t\t\t\t.
```

i wanted the output as

```
 Example
to 
understand
 the current
 situation .
```

output in html

```
<br /> Example<br />to <br />understand<br /> the current<br /> situation .
```

and i managed to get this output

```
Example

to 
understand

the current
situatuion .
```

with this code

```
$str='\n\tExample\n\r\nto \nunderstand\n\r\n the current\n situatuion\t\t\t\t\t.';


 echo str_replace(array('\n', '\r','\t','<br /><br />' ),
            array('<br />', '<br />',' ','<br />'), 
            $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the subset of characters you want to replace, such as `\r\n`, `\n` and `\t`, a single regex should do the trick to replace all repeating instances of them with the same:

```
/(\r\n|\n|\t)\1+/
```

You can use that with PHP's [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to get the replacement effect:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n|\t)\1+/', '$1', $str);
```

Then, to make the output "HTML friendly", you can make another pass with either [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) or [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str_replace.php) (or both):

```
// convert all newlines (\r\n, \n) to <br /> tags
$str = nl2br($str);

// convert all tabs and spaces to &nbsp;
$str = str_replace(array("\t", ' '), '&nbsp;', $str);
```

As a note, you can substitute the `\r\n|\n|\t` in the above regex with `\s` to replace "all whitespace" (including regular spaces); I wrote it out specifically because you didn't mention regular spaces *and* in case you wanted to add additional characters to the list to replace.

**EDIT** Updated the `\t` replacement above to replace with a single-space instead of 4-spaces per a comment-clarification.

Comment: @SobinAugustine You'll have to explain a little further; how do you expect them to output and how are they displaying that's "incorrect" to you? The `str_replace()` I have above replaces any `\t` (a tab) with four spaces (the `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`) - if that's too long, you can adjust it (each `&nbsp;` is "one space").

Comment: actually'output in html' section describes my question. ie all continuous \n and \r will change to a single <br /> and all continuous \t changes to a single space.

Comment: @SobinAugustine That goes along with my last comment as well; I've updated my answer to better-show how to replace the tab characters with a single-space (much like you have in your question's example code). The `preg_replace()` has to come first though in-order to replace all of the consecutive `\t` characters with a single `\t`, and then use `str_replace()` to replace the `\t` with a `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this alternative.

```
$string = "\n\tExample\n\r\nto \nunderstand\n\r\n the current\n situation\t\t\t\t\t.";

$replacement = preg_replace("/(\t)+/s", "$1", $string);

$replacement = preg_replace("/(\n\r|\n)+/s", '<br />', $string);

echo "$replacement";

#<br /> Example<br />to <br />understand<br /> the current<br /> situation
```

.